# Flutter : Copy data from one dart list to another list by searching with element

Tags: android, flutter, list, dart

The list _data contain data from the csv file.

```
  List<List<dynamic>> _data = [];
  String key = "39";
  List<List<dynamic>> _tempdata = [];

  void _loadCSV() async {
    final _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/mycsv.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> _listData =
        const CsvToListConverter().convert(_rawData);
    setState(() {
      _data = _listData;
    });
}
```

**mycsv.csv data**

```
id,Name,Num,Batch
15,JERRY,PH123,G9
27,Tom,PH129,G8
39,Oggy,PH124,G9
45,Jack,PH125,G10
```

I need to
Get the data where `id == key(search element)` from the list "_data" and store it in new list named "_tempdata"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` function in `List`

```
List searchByKey(key) {
    return _data.where((row) => key == row[0]).toList();
}
```